# Visual Studio 2012 Form1.vb user input validation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, validation

I have connected the sql database to my vb project and the last feature I need is to validate the user input. Two of the textboxes needs to be validated when adding a new record.

txtName is the first textbox that consists of the following format: BCO103/T1/01 . 'BCO' will always stays the same, however the rest needs to be input by the user. Letters and numbers needs to stay in exact the same place.

txtModuleID is the second textbox that needs to be validated. The data for this field looks like this: BCO120 . Yet again, BCO will always stay the same, however the 3-digit number will change.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms project?  And what sorts of things have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is a Windows Forms project. I have tried try/catch block and a lot of IF functions.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you looking for?  Having a red exclamation point appear next to the data in error?  Or just a simple message box saying, "Field must be in the format "BCO" plus 3 digits"?  A separate message box for each field in error, or one that summarizes all the issues?

Answer (score 1):

Im sure you can use substrings for this

for example:

```
If txtModuleID.Text.Substring(0,2) = "BCO" And txtModuleID.Text.Substring... etc Then 'add other conditionals

blnValidated = True

Else

blnValidated = False

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If txtModuleID.Text.Trim.ToUpper().SubString(0,2).equals("BCO") and len(txtModuleID.Text.Trim) = 6 Then
   If txtModuleID.Text.Trim.SubString(3,5).isNumeric() Then
       //valid input
   Else
       //message prompt that last 3 digits of the input is not numeric
   End If
Else
       //message prompt that input has invalid format and that input must start with BCO
End IF
```

Substring (0, 2) means from 0 until 2... getting the sub string of the input with letters in index 0, 1 and 2. The rest follows.

As for the first input, please do expound. I didn't quite catch how you want it to be validated.